# Counting paths from center of square to edge

Tags: algorithm, logic, permutation, combinations, combinatorics

Suppose I've a square of size (2n+1)x(2n+1) for some n i.e. a square with odd side length.
Starting from the centermost cell I'm interested in counting the no. of ways of reaching any edge cell(as shown in the following figure). 
Only non-overlapping paths are allowed i.e. we can not revisit a cell if it has been visited already.

Following Figure shows a square with side 9(n=4) and two possible paths of length 5.

[image]

I think all paths will be of length range: [n to (2n-1)^2+1 ] 
Counting no. of Paths of Length:
1 - 0
2 - 0
3 - 0
4 - 4
5 - 32
6 - ...? 
But as the Path length increases I can't seem to unwrap all the possibilities. I know the symmetry comes into play here but is there any structured way to count all the paths?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To find paths that start at the center of the square board and finish at the borders, you can use a tweaked DFS ([Depth First Search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search)) where you will store already visited tiles so you don't step on them again.

There is indeed a lot of symmetry in the board. You can divide the number of searched paths by 4 just by noticing that:

- Starting from the center, you can go **`U`p**, **`D`own**, **`L`eft**, **`R`ight**
- All the paths that start going **`U`p** generate all other paths starting **`D`own**, **`L`eft**, **`R`ight** by rotation

Once you do that, you can go further by noticing that:

- Once you've gone **`U`**, you can go **`U`**, **`L`** or **`R`**
- All paths generated when you go **`L`** are the same ones generated when you go **`R`** by mirror symmetry.

You can repeat this several times until you reach the border of the square. The full amount of paths starting by going **`U`** will be:

- **`U-U-U-U`** (one path)
- 2 times paths starting with **`U-U-U-L`**
- 2 times paths starting with **`U-U-L`**
- 2 times paths starting with **`U-L`**

Once you count those, you have the full amount of paths by multiplying by four.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Going by your symmetry argument I think we can safely conclude that every path ending on `upper half of right-most boundary wall` (actually, any half-segment of any boundary wall) could be reflected in 8-symmetric ways. (except the 4 straight paths from the center of square to center of 4boundary wall)  I've written this naive DFS [code](http://ideone.com/PrNv7i), so is there an **efficient way** to limit/prune the DFS to search for paths that end only on say - `upper half of right most wall`? thus improving the run-time by a factor of 8.

Comment: Actually you can't use the symmetry arguments **and** prune by ending point because this would mean you end up exploring only paths that start going Up and end in the upper half of right most wall. Either you choose to prune by starting points as in my answer, either you prune by ending point. Pruning by starting point is much faster because you can't know if a path will end outside of the upper half of rightmost wall unless it ended in the wrong place, which means you explored all paths anyway.

Comment: Yes, looks like pruning from start is the right way to go for.